# Firebase Analytics: Why does Google recommend a "login" event but not "logout"?

Tags: analytics, firebase

After many years of using pageview-based Google Analytics, I'm trying to learn event-based Firebase Analytics.

According to the documentation, basic events like page impressions are tracked automatically.  On the [list of Google-recommended events to add yourself](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735), Google suggests adding a `login` event.

But there's no mention of a `logout` event.  Is there a reason why Google recommends tracking `login` but not `logout`?

Of course I can create my own custom `logout` event, which I will do.  This question is "why does Google recommend tracking only `login`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly because users either a) don't bother logging out, ever, or b) because logging out is what they do immediately before leaving the site.

Therefore, logging out is not *usually* a useful event to track since exits are already measurable as standard. This is unlike log in events, which are useful.

If you believe that users will be continuing to browse the site after logging out, then by all means track it.